# WCF tracing seems to be truncating

Tags: wcf

I have a REST WCF service that is being hosted in IIS.  I have turned on WCF tracing in the web.config with the following entry:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "D:\whateverpath\Traces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

My tracefile is generated but always gets truncated.  It doesn't seem to have a particular size limit, it varies between 40KB and 66KB.  Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing flush on the trace; it's possible that the trace was just waiting to be written out. To do that, add the element below under `<system.diagnostics>`

```
<trace autoflush="true"/>
```